# What is the URI for a Sharepoint Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate

What happened to the "Get Email Reminder" template? It seems to have disappeared from the Sharepoint menu AND Power Automate. Very inconvenient!

I am trying to do exactly what it used to do for a document library and don't know enough to figure out how to set up the "send http request to sharepoint" bit. How do I figure out the URI? That's my last missing piece.

Edit taken from comment:  I want to set an email reminder for when a document has been on file for 6 months that says that the document is due for review. It feels like a super easy thing (and it was with the little power automate drop down that was there a few weeks ago), but I've been struggling to do it from scratch

Comment: Get email reminder for what? What are you trying to achieve? Things change all the time. Don't get married to how things were. Explain what outcome you want and we can help you find a way to achieve that outcome.

Comment: Thanks for replying -- I want to set an email reminder for when a document has been on file for 6 months that says that the document is due for review. It feels like a super easy thing (and it was with the little power automate drop down that was there a few weeks ago), but I've been struggling to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that there ever was a SharePoint or Flow template for such a specific situation.

Conceptually, you need to create a scheduled flow, not one that triggered by something happening in a library. Filter the library to return only the documents that meet the criteria and then use a loop to send an email for each of the documents.

It might be easier to have a SharePoint library column with the due date and then build a SharePoint view that shows only documents due in the next xx days. The the reminder can be built from the "Get daily reminders in Email" template to go and check the view.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-reminder-flow-23c0e172-1fc1-4ac8-a9db-cd0b81d634d8   It's this one, but for whatever reason it doesn't exist anymore. Thanks for your help, I'll continue to fiddle around with it!

Comment: So far, I have :   - scheduled trigger, compose date (today plus 6 mths), compose end date (plus 1 day), Send http request to sharepoint (get files from document library), Get files (properties only, filter query using composed dates), condition if get file properties value is empty, then email reminder. The bit that is consistently not working for me is the Filter Query and the Uri section of the Send http request. (I copied the flow structure from an old flow that was auto-made via that template)

Comment: Several things: The flow in the link above does not seem to be tied to a specific document. It's just a reminder from a library. Second:  you don't need a SharePoint http request action. You don't need a URI. Use the SharePoint action to "get documents (properties only)". Filter that action to return only documents that meet the criteria. Then loop through the results of that action and send the emails.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it to work now, it was my OData syntax that wasn't correct, so I've since fixed that also. Thanks for your help, and yes, you are so right, I totally don't need that http request. I have no idea why the old template had it on there in the first place.